# Calculate conditional distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Here are the processes of signal $s_i$ and $s_j$:
\begin{equation}
s_i = \theta+\sigma\varepsilon_i
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
s_j = \theta+\sigma\varepsilon_j
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon_i$ and $\varepsilon_j$ are independent and normally distributed with mean $0$ and variance $1$. That is, $\varepsilon_i\sim N(0,1)$, $\varepsilon_j\sim N(0,1)$. $s_i$ and $s_j$ share the same $\theta$ and $\sigma$, where $\theta$ is independent to $\varepsilon_i$ and $\varepsilon_j$ and $\sigma$ is a positive constant. **My question** is, given condition $s_i$ and $\theta>k$, what is the conditional distribution of $s_j$? My solution is given by:
\begin{equation}
Prob(s_j\leq x|s_i, \theta>k)=Prob(s_j-s_i\leq x-s_i|s_i,s_i-\sigma \varepsilon_i>k)=Prob(\sigma (\varepsilon_j-\varepsilon_i)\leq x-s_i |s_i, \varepsilon_i<\frac{s_i-k}{\sigma})
\end{equation}
But then I do not know how to move on... Can anyone teach me how to calculate this conditional distribution? Thanks!

Comment: For an event $A$, random variables $Z, S$, and constants $s, w$, one way is to use 
$$ P[A | Z\leq w, S=s] = \frac{P[A \cap\{ Z \leq w\}| S=s]}{P[Z \leq w | S=s]} $$

Another is to use
$$ P[A| Z\leq w, S=s] = \int_{z=-\infty}^{\infty} P[A|Z=z, Z\leq w, S=s] f_{Z|Z\leq w, S=s}(z)dz$$

Comment: @Michael  I'll try it, thank you so much!!